# Socket.io path on server side (Node.js) and client side (Angular)

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I have socket.io working locally. `http://localhost:3000` is URL for Node.js backend and `http://localhost:4200` URL for frontend Angular.

But it does not work when I deploy the app.

Folder structure:

**parent-folder-name**

```
 -backend folder

 -frontend files
```

All files of Angular located directly in the parent folder.

URLs:

`http://mydomainnameexample.com/parent-folder-name/backend`
`http://mydomainnameexample.com/parent-folder-name/` (frontend)

Code:

Client: `this.socket = io('http://mydomainnameexample.com/parent-folder-name/');`

Server side:

```
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('A client is connected!');

  socket.on('index', () => {
    console.log('socketData: ');
    testController.index(socket);
  });
});
```

I do have `404` in the console for this URL:
`http://mydomainnameexample.com/parent-folder-name/backend/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MQnDIEb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the server side (Node.js) I added the path:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {path: 'parent-folder-name/backend/socket.io'})`
```

And Client side:

```
this.socket = io('http://mydomainnameexample.com', { path: 'parent-folder-name/backend/socket.io' });
```